# The security protocol cannot verify the incoming message?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

i develop a application  security wcf use Message mode:

```
         <security mode="Message">                      
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"/>
</security>
```

it's run on local machine good, but when i run it to a pc other it notifice error:

> The security protocol cannot verify the incoming message

use tracing i see:

> The security timestamp is invalid because its creation time
>   ('2012-07-17T21:08:43.211Z') is in the future. Current time is
>   '2012-07-17T07:08:48.769Z' and allowed clock skew is
>   '00:05:00'.

what is problem? thanks

Comment: Contribute in building up the community (Zero acceptance is disheartening) meanwhile [check this : increase skew time](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c3bdb91c-f3e3-4670-b9b9-fe908f0595f2/)

Comment: And when you want to start therewith?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be (if you don't need time stamp) - You can disable adding timestamp to the security headers in your request and WCF won't expect it in the response. Code taken from [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/09/Tracing-WCF-Messages) link

```
// *** Don't include TimeStamp header - so server won't expect it back
// *** This allows results returned without any Soap Headers
BindingElementCollection elements = client.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
client.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
```